# asp:ListBox is disabled inside css dropdown-menu class

Tags: css, asp.net, listbox

i am showing asp.net Listbox (with multiselect) and dropdown control inside dropdown-menu class. Listbox is not opening or expanding when i click on it while dropdown is working fine. If i place listbox outside dropdown menu class then it's selectable again.

```
<div class="position-relative float-right">
                                        <i class="ft-filter mb-5" role="button" id="CO0" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></i>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" aria-labelledby="CO0" style="border-block-color: navy !important">
                                            <div class="row" style="padding: 15px">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="basicInput">Department</label>
                                                        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstDepartmentForDisposal" SelectionMode="Multiple" CssClass="form-control"></asp:ListBox>
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfDepartmentForDisposal" runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfAllDepartmentForDisposal" runat="server" />
                                                    </fieldset>

                                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="helpInputTop">Item</label>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddItemForDisposal" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" onchange="refAssetsByDisposal();return false;"
                                                            DataValueField="Name" AutoPostBack="False" CssClass="form-control">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" Width="150px" CssClass="btn btn-facebook mr-2" Style="color: white" OnClientClick="refAssetsByDisposal();return false;" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

[image]

i tried to place listbox outside dropdown class and its working fine there. so its only dropdown class which blocking listbox to expand.

Comment: A listbox does not drop down, it should display as a box and list of items for user to select items. Are you using some 3rd party JavaScript library with the listbox? And details such as using an update panel? And are you using some kind of dialog system here? (again that's going to be some JavaScript library. All of these missing bits of information are MASSIVE HUGE LARGE details that will effect this.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal. I am using multiselect third party library.  Listbox is inside updatepanel but its not effecting the functionality.

Comment: Without a update panel nesting inside of your div most certainly seems to make this fail. As I stated, since there are 100's of libraires that allow multi-select, then a solution to your issue going to have 100's of different answers based on the code and js libraries you are using here. Hence they matter huge unless you telling me that removing the UP and still nesting inside of your existing divs means the multi-select works, and you noting it does not. Obviously then your multi-select is being effected by other code or routines you are using here.  We need more markup and what js you using